# Get Download Request from Google Keyword Planner

Tags: javascript, csv, keyword

Is there any way to receive the request for CSV Downloads inside the Google Keyword Planner so you can trigger it via an external web application?

After performing a keyword search in Google Keyword Planner you are able to download your results as CSV-file. This function opens in a new tab - I would like to be able to trigger this event from outside.